# Вложенность проверок в юнит тестах

Tags: юнит-тесты

Не знаю что делать с юнит-тестированием. Попробую объяснить на примере. Например есть 2 следующих класса

```
 class B {
   public string bar(str){
      if (str == null) throw Exception("some error")
      return "Hi " + str; 
   }
 }

 class A {
   var _b;

   public A (B b){
     _b = b;
   }

   public string foo(str){
     return _b.bar(str);
   }
 }
```

Для foo класса А я напишу тест:
1. проверить что вызывается b.bar с корректными данными и возвращает ответ

Для bar класса B я напишу 2 теста:
1. проверить что при str==null будет ошибка
2. вернется строка "Hi" + str

Собственно сам вопрос. Нужно ли проверять что при вызове A.foo(null) будет ошибка?

Comment: Ну если она заложенна логикой(к примеру валидацию вы проверяете в том методе и должна выборсится ошибка), то да

Comment: @Chubatiy просто если допустим у меня есть сервис который может кинуть ошибку, то во всех местах где он используется тестировать что и вызывающий его (сервис) код тоже кидает ошибку?

Comment: Я думаю что нет. Только в том случае, если вы хотите протестировать, как отреагирует клиентский код/сервис или в случае валидации, как я написал выше. Сомневаюсь, что он будет выбрасывать различные ошибки, в зависимости от места вызова. Поэтому хватит и одного теста - который проверит корректность генерации ошибки вашего сервиса и всё.

Comment: @Chubatiy хорошо) спасибо

Comment: не за что. Успехов!